# How to unmarshall JAX-RS Webservice response (JSON Array) correctly?

Tags: json, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, gson

I have some problem using Jersey REST webservices.

I have the following domain class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String forename;
    private String role;

    public User() {
        // required for JAXB
    }

    // + Getters + Setters
}
```

and the following resource class:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @GET
    public User[] getUsers() {
        User[] users = ... // Users from DB 
        return users;
    }
}
```

If I request that resource (/users) I get the following json response:

```
{
 "user":  
 [
  {
   "id":"1",
   "email":"Toby@email.com",
   "forename":"Toby",
   "role":"admin"
  }
 ,
  {
   "id":"2",
   "email":"Rob@email.com",
   "forename":"Rob",
   "role":"developer"
  }
 ]
}
```

On the client side (where I have the same User.class) I want to unmarshall this JSON response back to the corresponding POJOs. That means in this example I would like to get two Object of type User. I did some experimental stuff with GSON like

```
User[] users = gson.fromJson(JSONString, User[].class)
```

but was not able to get it working. Exception:

```
JSONParseException: Expecting object but found array
```

Can anyone tell me what Iam doing wrong here? Or is my json format the problem?

**Edit:** 
Tried it with an own implementation of a collection type adapter as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650951/android-json-gson-prom):

```
Type usersType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
users = gson.fromJson(reader, usersType);
```

Now Iam getting an JsonParseException:

```
The JsonDeserializer failed to deserialize Json Object {"user":[{"id":"1","email":"Toby@email.com","forename":"Toby",....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really was the format of the json response! with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794713/java-util-map-to-json-object-with-jersey-jaxb-jackson) I bypassed the Object->XML->JSON way to a direct Object->JSON transformation which leads to a clean JSON syntax interpretable by gson. will update the answer with my full example source soon.