# REST API Array woes

Tags: java, arrays, rest

I want to upload a list of objects to my webserver through a REST API. I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with a REST call?

The object looks like this:

```
class Position {
    private Date date;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
}
```

Can I do it with something like this:

`http://www.example.com/positions?userId=abc&position1=position1&position2=position2` ?

Or should I create a JSON representation of it and upload/put that to the webserver?

Comment: Yes, this should be standard functionality with Jersey, this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823070/how-to-unmarshall-jax-rs-webservice-response-json-array-correctly

Comment: will you consider sending a payload with your HTTP request? If not you will have to find some hack in the url parameters. Amazon has something similar (see examples on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CartAdd.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the Jersey REST framework. It might be enough just to enable the [POJO mapping feature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html).

We do something similar in our project, where we marshal Java data types into JSON, and return that in our HTTP response.

Comment: Very doable - we use RestEasy but it's almost the same.  Generally, we just JAXB annotated our POJOs and then your REST layer can work with the JSON.  We created a helper method, `String toJSON(Ojbect obj)` that used the ObjectMapper to write the JSON value and that String gets put in the request body and you set content-type = 'application/json' and off you go.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Is it possible to use Google gson for this as well?

Answer (score -1):

Use http POST instead of GET. You don't have to use json.